# Overrides a method with all parents works in that method?

Tags: java, oop, parent

I have a class B, that extends from class A, class B overrides a class A's method:

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA {

    @Overrides
    protected void DoSomething() {
        super.DoSomething();
        // Some ClassB code here, called WorkB
    }
}
```

After that, I create a class B object, and I need do something extra in addition to what A's version in DoSomething():

```
ClassB objB = new ClassB() {

    @Overrides
    protected void DoSomething() {
        // I need to do something more here
    }

}
```

I need to know if I can do ALL of `ClassA` works, `ClassB` works, then add some other code for objB in this method? I have a solution: create a `public method` in `ClassB`, that do `WorkB`, then in `objB`, just call the method. But I want to know if there is/are another way (no matter worse or better my solution!).

EDIT: I will summarise the question so you can easily understand it:

- `Class A`'s `doSomething` method does something called WorksA.
- `Class B` overrides `doSomething`, call super.doSomething() and some extra code, which mean it does `WorksA` and an extra called `WorksB`.
- Object `objB` `doSomething()` method **has to** do `WorksA`, `WorksB` and another extra called `WorksBExtra`.

That's all.

Comment: I think you answered your own question. You got it.

Comment: @Romain Hippeau: That solution sudden appear in my head when I was typing this question, so I'm not sure yet. And, I want to know if there is another way :)

Comment: @W.N I think I didn't get the question or my simple answer is right. Are you ok with my answer below ?

Comment: @Manuel Selva: Edited so it is easier to understand.

Comment: @W.N, ok so my answer is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes just call `super.doSomething()` first and it will throw up until Class A and then Class B. After that you can do specific stuff.

```
public class A {
public void doSomething() {
    System.out.println("A, ");
}
```

}

```
public class B extends A {
public void doSomething() {
    super.doSomething();
    System.out.println("B, ");
}
```

}

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b = new B() {
        @Override
        public void doSomething() {
            super.doSomething();
            System.out.println("new B");
        }
    };
    b.doSomething();
}
```

Outputs A, B, new B

Comment: His issue is that he doesn't have `super.doSomething()` inside his ClassB.

Comment: Ok, never mind.  I read the question 3 times and understand it differently 3 times.  Yes, your solution will do what (s)he needs in this case.

Comment: I think super inside obj still refer to `ClassA`, not `ClassB`, so only `ClassA`'s `doSomething` is called?

Comment: +1 - I added my own answer with a bit more detail, but this is right.

Answer (score 2):

Your object is an instance of an anonymous subclass of ClassB, and you can override in exactly the same way:

```
ClassB objB = new ClassB() {

    @Override
    protected void DoSomething() {
        super.DoSomething();
        // do something more here just for this object.
    }

}
```

This code will first call the `ClassB` version of `DoSomething()`, which calls the `ClassA` version.  So the net effect is to first do the `ClassA` stuff, then the `ClassB` stuff, then the stuff specific to the anonymous subclass.

I think you had the annotation wrong.  It's `@Override` with no "s".  Probably just a typo.

Also note that your `DoSomething()` is rather non-standard naming.  You'd be better off calling it `doSomething()` in accordance with the way methods are usually named in Java.

Comment: I didn't know super refers to class B, not class A. And yes, it's just typo mistakes, thank you for your advice.

Comment: Yes. super always refers to the immediate superclass.  If there weren't an override in B, it would find it in A, but with an override in B it will call that.

Comment: So, `objB` is a "child" of `ClassB` if I understand this way? Is it correct? I thought only a class that extends other class is called "child" (which mean `objB` is not "child" of `ClassB`), and that's why I thought super refers to `ClassA`.

Comment: objB is an instance of an anonymous subclass of ClassB.  I don't like the word "child" here, but with this usage, the anonymous class would be the "child".